# Test Angular 9 (TypeScript) with Mocha and JavaScript Syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

We recently migrated to Angular 9 (Type Script) from Angular.js and would like to continue writing our tests in Mocha, but keep the JavaScript syntax (not writing tests in TypeScript Mocha).

Is that possible to write JavaScript test for Type Script code (I know that JavaScript syntax is possible to write, this is not what I am asking) - the question is - is it possible to test the actual TypeScript components of Angular?

Any guides/article will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: TypeScript is basically just a (visual) layer on top of JavaScript. Either create `.ts` files and write default JavaScript code, or create `.spec.js` files and write JavaScript. Either way, it should "just work". If anything you need to check if you have settings defined that mocha will only load certain extensions for your tests.

Comment: We fully write TypeScript code in the .ts files. We just want the tests to be in JavaScript (not TypeScript)

Comment: Yes, I am fully aware of that. As I said, you don't *have* to write TypeScript. TS just adds typing functionalities virtually on top of your JavaScript code. In fact, after compiling it still is regular JavaScript code that's prone to type manipulations just like before. It will just help you while developing. So, what happens if you just write regular JavaScript code in your specs?

Comment: Ok, I understand now what you mean. To keep using the .ts extension and to write the JavaScript code inside it. This is exactly what we needed, thank you. It didn't work at first, so I guess we missed some configurations. This is why I was asking for some links to guides.

Comment: You are welcome. I will just post this comment as an answer so we can close this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required behavior **should** just work as you want it.

TypeScript is basically just a (visual) layer on top of JavaScript.
Either create a `.spec.ts` files and write default JavaScript code, or create `.spec.js` files and write JavaScript. Either way, it should "just work".
If anything you need to check if you have settings defined that mocha will only load certain extensions for your tests.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me here. You should elaborate a little on what you tried and what exactly is not working then. You should not need to write ANY TypeScript in order to just "run" other TypeScript functions and assert its output.

Comment: I do know that JS is supported and is result of a TypeScript code. The question is, is this even possible to test Angular TypeScript like that?

Comment: Yes, just write plain old JavaScript code in your tests. If you can create a sample repo that demonstrates the issues you're having I may help you further.

Comment: Finally we will go with TypeScript syntax for our tests (Mocha with TypeScript)